# Escaping HTML tag using Twing

Tags: html, twig, escaping

Am trying to put an html tag using in Twig but i don't know how to do that

This is my code:

```
<span class={{item.class_bold}}>{{ item.value_2 ?  trait ~ item.value_2 : ""}} </span>
```

The span is empty when the `item.value_2` doesn't exist, so i need to make a ternary condition around the span.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution is using if statement.

```
{% if item.value_2 is defined and item.value2 %}
    <span class="{{ item.class_bold }}">{{ trait ~ item.value2 }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank but i want to use a ternary condition not a simple if.

Comment: You need to use 'raw' filter - https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html. Example: {{ true ? ('<span>' ~ var ~ '</span>')|raw : '' }}

Comment: and if i want to add a class to the span, is that correct ?? : ```{{ item.value_2 ? ('<span class=' ~ item.class_bold ~ '>' ~ item.value_2  ~ '</span>')|raw : '' }}```

Comment: Yes, but class should be inside " ". '<span class="{{ item.class_bold }}">'

Comment: that's not working, because in the google inspector i don't have the class name but i have this ```class="{{ item.class_bold }}"```

Comment: '<span class="' ~  item.class_bold ~ '">'

Comment: yeah that's what i said no ? x/

Comment: If item.class_bold contains "class1 class2" following **('<span class=' ~ item.class_bold ~ '>' ~ item.value_2 ~ '</span>')|raw** will be rendered as **<span class=class1 class2>...<span>**.

Comment: will, thas's works for me :    ```{{ item.value_2 ? ('<span class=' ~ item.class_bold ~ '>' ~ item.value_2  ~ '</span>')|raw : '' }}```

Answer (score 0):

that's works for me :

```
{{ item.value_2 ? ('<span class=' ~ item.class_bold ~ '>' ~ item.value_2  ~ '</span>')|raw : '' }}
```

Comment: You can omit the last part if it's an empty string e.g. `{{ item.value_2 ? ('<span class=' ~ item.class_bold ~ '>' ~ item.value_2  ~ '</span>')|raw }}`